# Comparison of normal derivatives

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $A$ and $B$ be open bounded simply connected sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$, $d \in \{2,3\}$, such that $\bar{A} \subset B$. Denote the boundaries of these domains as $\partial A$ and $\partial B$, respectively. Consider the following problems:

$$
\Delta u_1 = 0 \ \text{in $B\setminus A$}, \quad u_1 = 1 \ \text{on $\partial B$}, \quad u_1 = 0 \ \text{on $\partial A$}\\
\Delta u_2 = 0 \ \text{in $B\setminus A$}, \quad \nabla{u_2} \cdot \nu = g \ \text{on $\partial B$}, \quad u_2 = 0 \ \text{on $\partial A$},
$$
where $\nu$ is the inward unit normal to $B\setminus A$, and $g$ is a positive valued function.

Is it possible to compare the normal derivatives of $u_1$ and $u_2$ on $\partial A$? More precisely, I want to know the sign of $\nabla u_1\cdot \nu - \nabla u_2 \cdot \nu$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No definitely not. Let $n=3$, $B=B_R$, $A=B_1$, $R>1$, and $g=1$. You can explicitly solve your equations to obtain $$u_1(x)=\frac{1-\vert x\vert^{-1}}{1-R^{-1}}$$ and $$u_2(x) =R^2(1-\vert x \vert^{-1}). $$ Then on $\partial A=\partial B_1$, \begin{align*}
\partial_\nu u_1 - \partial_\nu u_2 &= \frac R{R-1}-R^2 . \tag{$\ast$}
\end{align*} As $R\to \infty$, $(\ast) \to -\infty$ and as $R\to1^+$, $(\ast) \to +\infty$ so $\partial_\nu u_1 - \partial_\nu u_2$ can actually be any real number by picking the correct $R$.

---

That being said the above computation shows that it should be possible to prove what you want under the additional assumption that $A \setminus B \subset B_{R+\varepsilon}(x_0)\setminus  B_{R}(x_0)$ for some $x_0 \in \mathbb R^n$, $R>0$, and $\varepsilon >0$ with $\varepsilon$ very small.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please clarify what do you mean by the additional assumption that dist$(\partial A, \partial B)$ is sufficiently small. Are you saying this is also true in general?

Comment: Well in my computation $(\ast) \to +\infty$ as $R\to 1^+$ so in this case $\partial_\nu u_1 - \partial_\nu u_2 \geqslant 0 $ provided $R$ is sufficiently close to 1. On rereading this assuming $\operatorname{dist}(\partial A,\partial B)$ is not what I originally had in mind.

Comment: What I meant was if you additionally assume that $A \setminus B \subset B_{R+\varepsilon}(x_0)\setminus  B_{R}(x_0)$ for some $x_0 \in \mathbb R^n$, $R>0$, and $\varepsilon >0$ with $\varepsilon$ very small then I expect that the statement $\partial_\nu u_1 \geqslant \partial_\nu u_2$ on $\partial A$ is true

Comment: How small $\epsilon$ needs to be should depend on how 'big' $B$ is and how large $g$ is

Comment: Many thanks for your further explanation. I think I now understand the additional assumption.  Thank you again.